# USB serial lost connection, how to restart?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I have the following setup:

[MacBook]--Thunderbolt 4-->[Monitor]--USB-->[ESP32]

A MacBook connected through Thunderbolt 4 to a monitor; this monitor has two USB ports, one of which I connect to an ESP32 (microcontroller, like an Arduino).

It works fine.

However, after macOS sleep and wake, the serial port goes nowhere, and I can't use my ESP32. The current workaround is to unplug the thunderbolt cable from the MacBook, wait around 30 seconds, and plug again.

Right now, if I run the command

```
ls /dev/cu.*
```

There is only `/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port`, no serial ports.

So, my question is: How to reset/restart the serial ports to be recognized **without** unplugging the cable?

Comment: If you need to leave it unplugged for 30 seconds, it sounds like it’s a power issue.  I would put that ESP into a (powered) USB hub as a buffer between the monitor and the ESP.

Comment: The ESP32 keeps running, it is connected to AWS IoT Core sending messages every 10 seconds, I can see it running.

Comment: I didn’t say the ESP stopped.  I suspect it’s sending current (5V perhaps?) over the USB line and causing a power issue with the monitor.

Comment: Unplugging and plugging the ESP doesn't work either